# HTTP PUT File/BLOB with fetch or XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is it possible to upload a File with `fetch`? I'm not talking about `FormData`, but I want to be the file the actual body of the `HTTP` `PUT`, and the `Content-Type` the correct ContentType?

If its not possible with `fetch`, can it be dont with the `XMLHttpRequest`? This code isnt working for me (event is a `drop` event):

```
fetch('/foo', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: event.dataTransfer.files[0],
});
```

**Edit:**

I'm specifically talking about FILE uploads. This *does* work if `body` is a Text, but not if its a `FILE`/`BLOB`!

Comment: Seems that `fetch('/new.html', {method: 'PUT', body: '<h1>TEST</h1>'})` is doing what is expected. Does your server support PUT?  Netowrk tab of FF shows that a PUT is executed with the correct body.

Comment: @Reflective it *does* work for Text, but not for a BLOB :/

Comment: Yes you can. But are you sure `event.dataTransfer.files[0]` is indeed a file? Don't you need a `getAsFile()` method? What is `event`? Did you tried to use an file input first to test your logic?

Answer (score 3):

You can just create the form data, something like:

```js
const body = new FormData();
const file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
body.append('files', file , file.name);

fetch('/foo', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body
});
```

However, if you want to just send the data directly you'll have to change the header and use a `Blob`:

```js
const body = new Blob(event.dataTransfer.files, { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

fetch('/foo', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }),
  body
});
```